# How to get metadata from Libextractor into a struct

Tags: c, metadata, extract

I want to use Libextractor to get keywords/metadata for files.
The basic example for it is -

```
struct EXTRACTOR_PluginList *plugins
= EXTRACTOR_plugin_add_defaults (EXTRACTOR_OPTION_DEFAULT_POLICY);

EXTRACTOR_extract (plugins, argv[1],
                 NULL, 0, 
                 &EXTRACTOR_meta_data_print, stdout);
  EXTRACTOR_plugin_remove_all (plugins);
```

However, this calls the function EXTRACTOR_meta_data_print which "prints" it to "stdout"
I'm looking at a way to get this information to another function - i.e. pass or store this in memory for further working. The documentation was not clear to me. Any help or experience regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to install libextractor and failed to get it working (it always returns a NULL plugin pointer upon call to `EXTRACTOR_plugin_add_defaults()`), so what I will write next is *NOT TESTED*:

from : http://www.gnu.org/software/libextractor/manual/libextractor.html#Extracting

```
Function Pointer: int
(*EXTRACTOR_MetaDataProcessor)(void *cls,
const char *plugin_name,
enum EXTRACTOR_MetaType type,
enum EXTRACTOR_MetaFormat format,
const char *data_mime_type,
const char *data,
size_t data_len)
```

and

Type of a function that libextractor calls for each meta data item found.

```
cls
    closure (user-defined) 
plugin_name
    name of the plugin that produced this value;
    special values can be used (i.e. '<zlib>' for
    zlib being used in the main libextractor library
    and yielding meta data); 
type
    libextractor-type describing the meta data; 
format basic
    format information about data
data_mime_type
    mime-type of data (not of the original file);
    can be NULL (if mime-type is not known); 
data
    actual meta-data found 
data_len
    number of bytes in data

Return 0 to continue extracting, 1 to abort.
```

So you would just have to write your own function called whatever you want, and have this declaration be like:

```
int whateveryouwant(void *cls,
const char *plugin_name,
enum EXTRACTOR_MetaType type,
enum EXTRACTOR_MetaFormat format,
const char *data_mime_type,
const char *data,
size_t data_len)
{
    // Do your stuff here
    if(stop)
        return 1; // Stops
    else
        return 0; // Continues
}
```

and call it via:

```
EXTRACTOR_extract (plugins, argv[1],
                   NULL, 0, 
                   &whateveryouwant,
                   NULL/* here be dragons */);
```

Like described in http://www.gnu.org/software/libextractor/manual/libextractor.html#Generalities "3.3 Introduction to the libextractor library"

[here be dragons]: That is a parameter left for the user's use (even if it's redundant to say so). As defined in the doc: "For each meta data item found, GNU libextractor will call the ‘proc’ function, passing ‘proc_cls’ as the first argument to ‘proc’."

Where "the `proc` function" being the function you added (`whateveryouwant()` here) and `proc_cls` being an arbitrary pointer (can be anything) for you to pass data to the function. Like a pointer to `stdout` in the example, in order to print to `stdout`. That being said, I suspect that the function writes to a FILE* and not inevitably to `stdout`; so if you open a file for writing, and pass its "file decriptor" as last `EXTRACTOR_extract()`'s parameter you would probably end with a file filled with the information you can currently read on your screen. That wouldn't be a proper way to access the information, but if you're looking into a *quick and dirty* way to test some behavior or some feature; that could do it, until you write a proper function.

Good luck with your code!

Comment: It worked. Thank you!
After reading your answer, I read the documentation with a clear mind. It's all in there, really!!!